# Erlang: spawn_link processes are not killed when everything shuts down normally

Tags: erlang, exit, spawn

Module test:

```
tester() ->
    receive
        X -> 
            erlang:display("message.."),
            tester()
    end.


initialize() ->
    spawn_link(?MODULE, tester, []),
    erlang:display("Started successfully.").
```

REPL:

```
length(erlang:processes()). -> 23
Pid = spawn_link(test, initialize, []).
length(erlang:processes()). -> 24
exit(Pid).
length(erlang:processes()). -> 24
```

It seems that the spawned tester process is still running! How do i make sure that when i exit my application, all spawn_link process are killed too?

Comment: `exit(Pid)` will actually fail because the process running `test:initialize/0` will return almost instantaneously. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are actually starting two Erlang processes, not one. The first one, to which you are sending the `exit` signal, dies before you even send the exit signal, so the `exit` has no effect.

The first process you start in the shell in this line:

```
Pid = spawn_link(test, initialize, []).
```

This process starts executing the `initialize` function, in which it starts the second process, and then it dies because there is nothing else to do. This is the process to which you are trying to send the `exit` signal.

To fix this simply return the correct `Pid` from the initialize function:

```
initialize() ->
    Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE, tester, []),
    erlang:display("Started successfully."),
    Pid.
```

And start it directly:

```
Pid2 = test:initialize().
```

Then you will be able to kill it with `exit(Pid2).`

Comment: I understand it now, but still spawn_link is bidirectional, so when initialize process is killed, it should kill tester process also. But this isn't the case. And how can i do that?

Comment: The first process isn't killed, it dies before you manage to send the exit signal to it because there is no more code to execute. And when a process dies because of that reason it is said that it exits normally, so the link between processes doesn't trigger the other process to die. See Receiving Exit Signals in http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id86927 You could add `exit(something).` at the end of the initialize function. That way the process will not end normally and the linked process will die with it.